# IntelliJ IDE font broken after Windows upgrade

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, ide

I have upgraded to Windows 10 and the font being used in the IDE is no longer monospaced and I cannot change. This what the options screen looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the Editor font settings are grayed out and cannot be changed.

Even though it says "Monospaced", the IDE editor font is not monospaced which is insanely annoying because space indents are no longer lining up. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the font, because you've selected the `Default` scheme name, which is read-only.

Click on `Save as` and enter a scheme name to make a copy, which will become editable.